# "Select is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting '(' WITH"

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm currently attempting to run a SQL query and am given the error: `"Select is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting '(' WITH"`. I've read through other posts with this same error, and it seems like it's related to missing commas in the subquery. To my knowledge, I'm not missing any commas.

```
SELECT employees.Location, AVG(employees.salaries) as AvgLocSal
FROM employees,
        (SELECT employees.Location, AVG(employees.salaries) as b
        FROM employees
        GROUP BY employees.Location) as otherSal
GROUP BY employees.Location
HAVING AvgLocSal >= all(otherSal.b);
```

In short, I'm comparing average salaries across locations, and finding the location with the highest salary.

I can successfully do this by putting the subquery in the HAVING clause (as shown below), but I'm really not sure why the above query is giving the error.

```
SELECT Location, AVG(salaries) as AvgLocSal
FROM employees
GROUP BY Location
HAVING AvgLocSal >= all(
                        SELECT AVG(salaries)
                        FROM employees
                        GROUP BY Location
                        );
```

I could simply ORDER the list by salaries and then LIMIT to 1, however that would fail to give the desired results if two salaries were the same.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Nash

Comment: Do you mean to join to the nested relation? If so, you should use an actual `JOIN` statement.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn , I don't want to join them, just compare them.

Comment: The syntax for all is operand comparison_operator ALL (subquery) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/all-subqueries.html

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. And If I were to put "all(SELECT b FROM OtherSal)", this still wouldn't work because OtherSal is also generated in a subquery. So I was just taking the wrong approach. Thanks for help! I could mark this as the answer if it were posted below.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you want to average salaries across locations and finding the location with the highest salary. Following shall give you the expected output.

```
SELECT Location, AVG(salaries)
FROM employees
GROUP BY Location
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT MAX(avgSalary.salaries)
    FROM (SELECT AVG(salaries) AS 'salaries' FROM employees GROUP BY Location) AS avgSalary;
```